# AS3 Pass Object

Tags: actionscript-3

I have 3 Classes.

One is a Global class that has my function:

```
public static function getDistance(ObjOne, ObjTwo)
{
    var distance = Math.sqrt( ( ObjOne.x - ObjTwo.x ) * ( ObjOne.x - ObjTwo.x ) + ( ObjOne.y - ObjTwo.y ) * ( ObjOne.y - ObjTwo.y ) );
    return distance;
}
```

Then I have a `MovieClip` that is the class: `Minion` and another called: `Turret`

In the `Minion` class I am calling: `Global.getDistance`

And setting the args to: `Global.getDistance(this, ?????)`

How can I get the Turret Object from the Turret class for the final param?

Comment: Need more information about how your program should work before giving a useful answer.  Are there only one Mionion and Turret instances in your game?  or are there multiple instances of each?  how do they relate to each other? (a bullet from a turret strikes a minion?)

Comment: I have have 3 turrets, and 3 waves of minions spawning at one time, each headed towards its own respective turret.

Comment: Also, what do you use the getDistance function for?

Comment: Distance will be used to tell the minions when to stop and start attacking the tower.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If each minion has a single turret that it is targeting, then you should hold a reference to the turret inside of your `Minion` class.  There should be no need for a static function to get distance (unless it's used for other things besides the minion/turret relation).

For your turrets to be aware of ALL minions (to decide which minion to attack), a good way to do this is to store them all in a statically assessable vector (array).

Here would be a sample of your Minion class:

```
public class Minion {
    public static var allMinions:Vector<Minion> = new Vector<Minion>(); //create a static array to store all your minions


    public var turret:Turret;

    public function Minion(targetTurret:Turret):void {
        turret = targetTurret;
        this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,addedToStage,false,0,true);
        this.removeEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE,removedFromStage,false,0,true);
    }

    private function addedToStage(e:Event):void {
        allMinions.push(this); //add this minion instance to the array when it's added to the display list
    }

    private function removedFromStage(e:Event):void {
        //remove this minion instance from the array of all minions when it's removed from the display list
        var index:int = allMinions.indexOf(this);
        if(index >= 0){
            allMinions.splice(index,1);
        }
    }

    private function move():void { //whatever function you use to move the minion along
       //get distance here, using your local turret var
       getDistance(this,turret); //this could be a local function, or some static function somewhere - local is faster, especially if being called everyframe or in a loop.
    }

    //a function to take damage, returns true if still alive after the damage
    public function takeDamage(amount:Number):Boolean {
        this.health -= amount * armor;  //armor could be a value between 1 (no armor) and 0 (invincible)
        if(health <= 0){ 
             //die
             return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

This passes in the appropriate turret when you create a new Minion - `new Minion(turretInstance)`, and has a statically accessible array that holds all the minions that are on the display list at any given time.  It also adds a function to take damage

---

For the turrets to attack, you'd want to scan the array of all minions, and determine which are close enough to attack, either attack all (if that's the type of turret) or pick one (the closest one usually) to attack.

Turret class:

```
public var range:Number = 200; //how close to the turret a minion needs to be before it can attack
public var attackPower:Number = 10; //how much damage does this turret cause

public function attack():void {

    //this for loop goes through all the minions and finds the closest one
    var closestMinion:Minion;
    var tmpDistance:Number; //
    var distance:Number;
    for each(var minion:Minion in Minion.allMinions){
        distance = Math.sqrt( ( minion.x - this.x ) * ( minion.x - this.x ) + ( minion.y - this.y ) * ( minion.y - this.y ) ); //find the distance between the current minion in the loop and this turret
        if(distance < range && isNaN(tmpDistance) || distance < tmpDistance){  //if the distance of this minion is less than the current closest, make the current closest this one
            closestMinion = minion;
            tmpDistance = distance;
        }

    }

    //attack the closest one
    if(closestMinion){
        closestMinion.takeDamage(attackPower);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah I see what you did there. If you have ever heard of the game "League of Legends" basically I am making a flash version of that.

Comment: haven't heard of it, but I'm familiar with the tower defense genre of games.   if your minion is what is constantly moving, and needing to check the distance, then you should keep as much of the things it needs locally in it's own scope (for efficiency, and form).

Comment: Hi London, I could use some more help. Right now it is basically working as intended. However I am having trouble setting up a function in the Minion class that will allow me to have it "Take Damage". I have the healthBars setup but I can't find a way for the turret class to send to the minion class that it just took damage. Zipped Code: http://www.filedropper.com/leagueflash

Comment: You'd probably want to register an event on your turret within the minion class.   `turret.addEventListener("attack",attackHandler)`  have your `Turret` class dispatch that event when it fires it's weapon `dispatchEvent(new Event("attack"));`.  You could even make a custom event class that adds properties to the event like damage amount

Comment: Thank you, that is working very well. How can I get the event to only change the value of each minion though. Right now when I send the event it changes the health for all the minions.

Comment: If you only want the turret to hit one of the minions following it,  you'll probably want to restructure your code so it's the turrets that are aware of the minions.   I'll update the answer by Monday (Pacific Standard Time) to give you some suggestions

Comment: Thank you, What I dont get is the health isnt static so why isnt it only changing the currently targeted minion. However I guess if all minions are listening for the event from the turret it has no way to know which minion it is ment for.

Comment: Yea, all minions listening to the same turret will all receive damage. I updated the code to show a different way to go about it.

Comment: Perfect, that is working much better. I can't figure out for the life of me why in the take damage function after health = 0 I have a remove child for the minion. Which works but the removed from stage event never triggers so the minion stays in the array and it keeps attacking the same minion and throwing errors. I could use a different method but I really was wondering why the event wasnt triggering.

Answer (score 0):

If there is only one Turret in your game, you could use the singleton design pattern.

```
private static var instance:Turret = null;

public static function getInstance()
{
    if(instance === NULL)
        instance = new Turret();
    return instance;
}
```

So you can call Turret.getInstance() and use your Turret object. Hope it helps. If you have more than one turret you should have a game class with an array or vector with all your turrets.

Comment: .. And if you want to extend Turret you're screwed. A single today is a multiple tomorrow. I would not recommend a singleton, its a problematic design pattern. A static instance in a datamanager is ok, but dont force just to have one, you might need variation or multiples.

Comment: Thats what i said. He should use it if he has only one turret. If not there should be a StageManager or something else, that has references to all the turrets and minions.

Comment: I will have Multiple Turrets, and also multiple minion "waves"

Comment: Singletons do have their usage, its a useful tool when you have multiple developers on a project and want to protect an instance and only one instance, I would not use one in this case however!

Comment: @MarkKnol Singleton classes are very useful. MinionManager/TurretManager classes could be a Singleton. With this class it could control minions and update targets for each one as more get built/destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what you exactly need, the type of the second parameter? Since your dealing with a global function, i would suggest to just use `DisplayObject` since both have x/y properties

```
public static function getDistance(clip1:DisplayObject, clip2:DisplayObject):Number     
{ 
   return Math.sqrt( ( clip1.x - clip2.x ) * ( clip1.x - clip2.x ) + ( clip1.y - clip2.y ) * ( clip1.y - clip2.y ) );
}
```

Comment: That is basically what I am using, what I need is how do I get the turret object while I am in the minion class? So I can compare the distance.